# Download entire webpage (html, image, JS) by Selenium Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I have to download source code of a website like www.humkinar.pk in simple HTML form. Content on site is dynamically generated. I have tried `driver.page_source` function of `selenium` but it does not download page completely such as image and javascript files are left. How can I download complete page. Is there any better and easy solution in python available?

Comment: What webdriver do you use? What browser?

Comment: I am using Chrome

Comment: did you find a good way @HafizMuhammadShafiq , i am in the same problem now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using Selenium

I know your question is about selenium, but from my experience I am telling you that selenium is recommended for **testing** and **NOT** for scraping. It is very **SLOW**. Even with multiple instances of headless browsers (chrome for your situation), the result is delaying too much.

### Recommendation

> Python 2, 3

This trio will help you a lot and save you a bunch of time.

- [Dryscrape](https://dryscrape.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)
- [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html)

> Do not use the parser of dryscrape, it is very SLOW and buggy. For
>   this situation, one can use BeautifulSoup with the `lxml` parser. Use dryscrape to scrape Javascript generated content, plain HTML and images.
>
> If you are scraping a lot of links simultaneously, i highly recommend
>   using something like ThreadPoolExecutor

### Edit #1

#### dryscrape + BeautifulSoup usage (**Python 3+**)

```
from dryscrape import start_xvfb
from dryscrape.session import Session
from dryscrape.mixins import WaitTimeoutError
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def new_session():
    session = Session()
    session.set_attribute('auto_load_images', False)
    session.set_header('User-Agent', 'SomeUserAgent')
    return session


def session_reset(session):
    return session.reset()


def session_visit(session, url, check):
    session.visit(url)
    # ensure that the market table is visible first
    if check:
        try:
            session.wait_for(lambda: session.at_css(
                'SOME#CSS.SELECTOR.HERE'))
        except WaitTimeoutError:
            pass
    body = session.body()
    session_reset(session)
    return body

# start xvfb in case no X is running (server)
start_xvfb()

SESSION = new_session()
URL = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45796411/download-entire-webpage-html-image-js-by-selenium-python/45824047#45824047'
CHECK = False

BODY = session_visit(SESSION, URL, CHECK)
soup = BeautifulSoup(BODY, 'lxml')

RESULT = soup.find('div', {'id': 'answer-45824047'})

print(RESULT)
```

Answer (score 0):

I Hope below code will work to download the complete content of the page.

```
driver.get("http://testurl.com")
pageurl=driver.current_url
page = requests.get(pageurl)
pagecontent=page.content

`pagecontent` will contain the complete code content
```

Answer (score -3):

It's not allowed to download a website without Permission. If you would know that, you would also know there is hidden Code on hosting Server, where you as Visitior has no access to it.

Comment: If I have access to hosting server then is it possible?